# OpenLayers 3: Sync/Unsync Different Maps Events

Tags: openlayers

Let's say I have N different maps on the screen, I want to be able based on a condition, let s say a value coming from a checkbox or a different control to be able to sync all the map events (zoom/pan/rotation) and unsync them accordingly.
 Can this be achieved in OpenLayers 3 using native API?